# How to discover the MAC address of machines in and over a network?

Tags: networking, mac-address, bios

How do I discover the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of machines in a network?

I need to discover the machines that are available just with only BIOS installed (*no* operating system present). And I need to find the MAC address of machines that are up.

I won't have physical access to the machines. This is for baremetal discovery!

Comment: Cross-site duplicate (on Server Fault): *[How to discover the MAC address of machines in a network?](http://serverfault.com/questions/176405)*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WinPcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap#WinPcap) to monitor the Ethernet traffic on your network in the same collision domain. So you could learn all the MAC addresses just as a switch does. You could also fake some [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) messages in order to create some traffic. But this only works with [PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) (which is actually made for this scenario) and in your own collision domain.

Comment: This is the best answer - most BIOSes won't respond to any traffic, so your only option is to wait for them to talk first.

Answer (score 1):

Since the machines probably don't have IP addresses, I don't think you have a chance to actively query them. They would need to answer packets sent to the broadcast MAC and for e.g. ICMP echo requests, they'd need to send packets with something like 0.0.0.0 as a source IP. This is common and allowed for BOOTP/DHCP, but I haven't seen anything like this implemented by BIOSes yet.

Maybe just logging all MACs that go over the wire with a tool like `arpwatch` would help? If the machines have PXE booting enabled, you should at least see some DHCP DISCOVERs, before they leave into eternal silence.

Answer (score 0):

A just-not-as-"nice" solution as the ones suggested above (working over a network is just comfortable):

If you have physical access to the machines: Plug in a monitor and look the MAC address up in the BIOS. If for some reason the MAC address isn't listed in the BIOS, you could enable [PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment). After reboot, when PXE is initializing, you're going to see the MAC address.

Comment: I won't have physical access to the machines. this is for baremetal discovery!

Answer (score 0):

Try the arp command. I am not sure it will be really helpful for you as it might only work for PC with an IP address (and likely to have an OS).

If your computers are connected to a switch I guess you can have this information from it. Many "modern" switches are able to provide you with that information, should you know which PC is connected to which port on the switch.